# extract element id, chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to know how I can take the id of an element that is activated in chrome.

so, I want to click on an element and then I want my extension to know what the id and or name of this active element is. I am mainly talking input text fields. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to manually listen to either `focus`, `click` or `mousedown` events (whichever works best for your needs) in a content script:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
    var el = event.target;
    console.log("Clicked element:", el, el.nodeName, el.id);
}, true);
```

Not all elements have id, so you would be better off working with whole received element `event.target`.